pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkTypeError: [CANNOT_INFER_SCHEMA_FOR_TYPE] Can not infer schema for type: `DoubleScalar`
Trying to write a Python program that creates a PySpark DataFrame using pyarrow.array with specified type pyarrow.float64().
However, I get the following error:

pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkTypeError: [CANNOT_INFER_SCHEMA_FOR_TYPE] Can not infer schema for type: DoubleScalar.

The minimum code is as follows
import pyarrow
import pyspark

session = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder \
                              .appName ("pyspark_pyarrow") \
                              .config ("spark.executor.memory", "2g") \
                              .config ("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2") \
                              .config ("spark.driver.host", "localhost") \
                              .config ("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
                              .getOrCreate()

session.sparkContext.setLogLevel ("DEBUG")

array = pyarrow.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], type=pyarrow.float64())

df = session.createDataFrame (array)

session.stop ()

Basically, I want to use 'float64' everywhere in my code.
How do I fix this issue while continuing to use pyarrow datatype for creating PySpark DataFrame?

You can't directly provide a pyarrow datastructure. You will need to first convert it into pandas Dataframe and then pass that to pyspark Dataframe constructor function.
pandas_series = array.to_pandas()
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'values': pandas_series})
df = session.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
df.show()


why do we need to convert pyarrow.array to pandas when Spark (and thus PySpark) uses Arrow as it's underlying memory representation ?

Pyspark constructor only allows pandas dataframe. You can directly read parquet file if the data is in file.

is there any other datatype that we can use other than pandas to create a PySpark dataframe ?
